# Spring Custom Converter Exception throwing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing a Spring custom converter which converts a `String` to `LocalDate`.

```
@Component
public class StringToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

  private static final String ISO_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

  @Override
  public LocalDate convert(String s) {
    try {
      new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT).parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    return LocalDate.parse(s);
  }
}
```

I want the converter to check if the string date is provided in format `"yyyy-MM-dd"` and if not to throw `BadRequestException` which is my custom exception handled by a custom `@ControllerAdvice` of mine.

The problem is that exception is never thrown out of this method, although parse exception happens when string not in format `'yyyy-MM-dd'` is provided.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing different concerns by trying to put both "convert data" and "handle Web responses" in the same place. Do one thing at a time and follow standard practices, which in this case means throwing `ConversionFailedException`. Spring will then understand what happened and take appropriate action based on your Web MVC configuration (such as returning a 400 status code to the client). If you want to provide custom error handling, have your advice handle the exception that the conversion service rethrows.

Note that in this specific case, this logic is already available by using `@DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
  private LocalDate referenceDate = LocalDate.now();

It doesn't work. When a date with invalid format is passed, it falls back to default.

Comment: @Christina You apply the annotation to the incoming parameter to tell the built-in Spring converter how to interpret it (and I think that's probably the default anyway).

Comment: public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getPersons(MyParameter parameter) 
The incoming parameter is object containing a LocalDate field.

Answer (score 0):

It would be recommended to use standard `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` annotation for converting to `java.time` types and catch `DateTimeParseException` in the advice.

You definitely want to avoid mixing up old `SimpleDateFormat` with `LocalDate.parse()`. `SimpleDateFormat` is lenient by default so it will parse invalid date like `2018-02-30` but `LocalDate.parse()` won't.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("2018-02-30")); // Fri Mar 02 00:00:00 GMT 2018
LocalDate.parse("2018-02-30"); // java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 30'
```

Comment: Since I have default value : 
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
  private LocalDate referenceDate = LocalDate.now();

It falls back to default when invalid date format is passed.